# Default Security measures in asp.net MVC framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I was wondering if in ASP.NET MVC5 are the session's identifiers Protected by default ? ( like example are the session IDs are not recoverable via JavaScript or any other browser scripts?)

Also ,does the server side offer security concerning the storage of information?

I was wondering if those features comes by default in the MV5 asp.net framework , or should I implement my own security measures

Because if we read the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx)

**inProc mode**, which stores session state in memory on the Web server. This is the default.

**StateServer mode,** which stores session state in a separate process called the ASP.NET state service. This ensures that session state is preserved if the Web application is restarted and also makes session state available to multiple Web servers in a Web farm.

But the real question is , are they encrypted by default?

thank you

Comment: Considering that the session id is stored in a cookie by default, I'd say they're definitely recoverable by JS.  Why would the session state be encrypted server-side?

Comment: @Amy Hi amy and thank you for considering my issue , to answer your question is I don't know , I'm doing a research to validate if the MVC5 framework encrypt session state information on the webserver (because Inproc mode do stores them but I need to know are they protected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All session data in the MVC frameworks are stored on server side . By means , if you want to secure  them .Try encrypting them locally so once they get transferred to the server they remain secured  more details are explained here :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx